# EntLib 5 Changing logging location at runtime

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

Is there another way to change the logging location of Logging block of entlib?
Currently i have the following code to do the change

```
     var location = CommonConfiguration.ErrorLogPath;
        ConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap();
        configFileMap.MachineConfigFilename = "AppName.exe.config";
        var entLibConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        LoggingSettings loggingSettings = (LoggingSettings)entLibConfig.GetSection(LoggingSettings.SectionName);
        RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData fileTraceListener = loggingSettings.TraceListeners.Get("Rolling Flat File Trace Listener") as RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData;
        fileTraceListener.FileName = Path.Combine(location, @"Log\Appname.log");
        entLibConfig.Save();
```

the issue with this is that when users don't have write access the change isn't being saved to the logging file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Using the Fluent Configuration API,like following unit test code:

```
     [Test]   
     public void TestLoggingWithFluentConfigurationAPI()   
     {  
         var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();   
         builder.ConfigureLogging()  
             .WithOptions  
             .DoNotRevertImpersonation()  
             .LogToCategoryNamed("Basic")  
             .SendTo.FlatFile("Basic Log File")  
             .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder()  
                             .TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter")  
                             .UsingTemplate(  
                                 "Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline Message: {message}{newline}Category: {category}{newline}"))  
             .ToFile("d:\\logs\\BasicTest.log") 
             .SendTo.RollingFile("Rolling Log files") 
             .RollAfterSize(1024)  
             .ToFile("d:\\logs\\RollingTest.log")  
              .LogToCategoryNamed("General")  
      .WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory()  
      .SendTo.SharedListenerNamed("Basic Log File");  

         var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource(); 
         builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);  

         EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current  
           = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource); 
         LogWriterFactory logFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configSource);  
         LogWriter logWriter = logFactory.CreateDefault();  
         logWriter.Write("This is test message", "Basic");  
         logWriter.Write("This is default message");  

         string logfilepath = Path.Combine("d:", "logs\\BasicTest.log");  
         Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(logfilepath)); 
         Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists("d:\\logs\\RollingTest.log"));

     }
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363(PandP.50).aspx